# Is it possible to create a dividend paying token that doesn't need the token holder to "claim" the tokens

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to create a dividend contract that contains a balance of token A which should be divided among holders of token B in proportion to what they have. but every solution I run into seems to require users to "claim" the dividends by initiating a transaction. is there any way to do this the same way reflection tokens get distributed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its because of the tax. If user claimed the gain he becomes responsible for the tax.

The other way would be to have a master transaction that will trigger payout to all in one tx. Then you just trigger it, covering the fees yourself